# comparing two table result set and find unmatched records and find the which record is mismatched in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables. first one is

```
name     role
XXX       engineer
yyy       tester
zzz       developer
```

second table is

```
name      role
xxx       tester
yyy       tester
aaa       developer
```

i need the result set is

```
name role        name    role
xxx  engineer    xxx     tester
zzz   developer   aaa     developer
```

please give the solution....

Comment: Please give your own attempt and why it didn't work. We are not here to do your (home)work.

Comment: `"please give the solution"`... very nice!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not taking orders for homework at the moment especially where the order has order in it "Please give the solution..." now.

Comment: I have more than 25 columns in my result set. So, I need the result set without mentioning column name. Because, I have 100 columns in table A and 25 columns in Table B.

Answer (score 0):

Following query can help you.
Here I have assumed that you are matching data by row index.
Means, data on same row index must be the same.

```
--CREATE TABLE 1
DECLARE @TBL1 AS TABLE(name varchar(10), role varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @TBL1
VALUES
('XXX', 'engineer'),
('yyy', 'tester'),
('zzz', 'developer')

--CREATE TABLE 2
DECLARE @TBL2 AS TABLE(name varchar(10), role varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @TBL2
VALUES
('xxx', 'tester'),
('yyy', 'tester'),
('aaa', 'developer')

--Final Query
Select T1.name, T1.role, T2.name, T2.role
From (Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY GETDATE()) as RNr from @TBL1) T1
Inner Join (Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY GETDATE()) as RNr from @TBL2) T2 on T1.RNr = T2.RNr
Where (T1.name != T2.name OR T1.role != T2.role)
```

In final query, I have written two sub queries to generate row numbers for both table.
Then I have joined both table by row number and in where condition mismatch is checked.

Comment: Thank you...But, I have more than 25 columns. So, I need the solution without mention column name .....